# To capture true-negative on Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

On `Travis CI` I like to test if a build fails as expected with a certain input, but still want the entire job succeeds. Is there a way to achieve this?

Closest I can think of is [allow_failures](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Rows-that-are-Allowed-to-Fail), but it's not sufficient because a job in question passes if it succeeds, which means there's a bug in my code. False-positive. I want to check true-negative.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm open for the reason of why this got -1.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the error value (or return value, or exit value) is `0` when your program exits with not `0` you can do one of two things:

You can do the trivial thing and put `!` before the invocation like this:

```
!test_that_should_fail
```

This will invert (as an unary `!` op would) `0` to `1` and anything non-`0` to `0`, ensuring, that the command will fail if it'd succeed.

You can also do an `if`-test, described in detail [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html), like so:

```
# This will store $? and make the expression's exit value `0`
test_that_should_fail; ERR=$?
if [ "$ERR" = "1" ]; then echo "The test's failed as it should"; fi
if [ "$ERR" = "0" ]; then echo "The test ain't failed, unacceptable"; fi
```

But tbh I'd rather make my tests internally handle "planned failures".